# WebAuthenticationResult - System.NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am trying to implement [Facebook authentication sample](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/sso/), 
when code reaches at;

```
 WebAuthenticationResult webAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
      WebAuthenticationOptions.None,loginUrl);
```

I am getting exception like below;

> Exception = {System.NotImplementedException: Not implemented
>
> at
>   Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions
>   options, Uri requestUri)    at
>   SonglyWindowsPhone.Views.Login.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End ...
>
> Message: The method or operation is not implemented.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WinRT it's [similar situation to *FilePickers*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631755.aspx) - you have to use [AuthenticateAndContinue method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/dn608115). Once you use the method, your app is deactivated and after finished authentication it will be activated, at that moment you should handle *OnActivated* event in app.xaml.cs:

```cs
protected async override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnActivated(args);
    var continuationEventArgs = args as IContinuationActivatedEventArgs;
    if (continuationEventArgs != null)
    {
        switch (continuationEventArgs.Kind)
        {
            case ActivationKind.WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuation:
                ValueSet data = continuationEventArgs.ContinuationData;
                // continue web authentication
                break;
                // rest of code
```

At the [WebAuthenticationBroker class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br227025) you will also find a link to a sample.

And [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn596094.aspx) is nice explanation with sample code.

Comment: I have an additional question for this, login from Facebook successfully activated OnActivated event on App.xaml on the other hand Login.xaml events (Load, NavigatedFrom, NavigatedTo) does not get triggered, and I cannot navigate user to Main.xaml. I also cannot use  Frame.Navigate in App.xaml page. How can I achieve that? Somehow App.xaml should let Login.xaml page to let know redirect user to Main.xaml after successful login.

Comment: @Teomanshipahi You should check if the frame is already in Window.Current, if not create new one. The best would be to follow some examples the first link in the answer. Also you should test your app with/without debugger attached - with debugger the app may not be suspended. Also you should remeber that your app may be terminated while not active, bt this should be handeled by suspension.

Comment: thanks example in the first link helped a lot and resolved my problem :)

Comment: This solution does not apply to Windows Phone 8.1, right? Because `AuthenticateAndContinue` ist not implemented there (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker.authenticateandcontinue.aspx). @Teoman Did you solve your problem for Windows Phone 8.1?

Comment: @HeinrichUlbricht You mean WP8.1 Silverlight or RunTime. If RunTIme, then I think the method should be there.

Comment: @Romasz Runtime. In Intellisense the method is missing and MSDN (see my link) says "Minimum supported phone: Windows 10 Mobile". :(

Comment: @HeinrichUlbricht That's weird - I'm successfully using this in WP8.1 Runtime - also link from my answer says that it should be available.

Comment: @Romasz Got it. I was using `WebAuthenticationBroker` from a portable class library that is used by the Windows Phone 8.1 project. There the method ist not available. When using `WebAuthenticationBroker`directly from the Windows Phone 8.1 project the method is there. I hate this. Thanks for the fast feedback!